# Using `box-sizing: border-box` with `inline-block` elements

Tags: css

I'd like to use the `box-sizing: border-box` CSS property to split a form into a left and right half:

```
<form class=container>
  <fieldset class=left>
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea name=description></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class=right>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type=text name=name />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

In order to make this work, I need to float both `<fieldset>` elements to the left:

```
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  marign-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

The problem is of course that since the `<fieldset>`'s are floated, they are no longer in-flow, and the `<form>` element gets a height of 0 (unless i add a clearfix or something).  If I remove the float property and change their display to `inline-block`, they're back in flow, but they no longer line-up next to eachother.

Is there some way to use `border-box` here without needing to add a clearfix element (or `:after` pseudo element)?

For reference, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/amXeB/1/) a fiddle that uses floats, and [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/amXeB/) a fiddle that uses inline-block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite a common problem.

Adding an `overflow` value on the container, will have the browser to recalculate the container's dimensions despite it have no not-floated elements.

```
.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

**[Before](http://jsfiddle.net/amXeB/2/)** and **[After](http://jsfiddle.net/amXeB/3/)**

Comment: Do you know if there is a specific reason for this behaviour?