# seems `border-box` not working with inline-block of `a` tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to integrate the `box-sizing` but seems not working. any one help me to understand the issue here..

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/b45qjhh5/)

```css
a{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:1rem;
}

a.active{
  border:0;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="active" href="#">EN</a><a href="#">FR</a>
```

Comment: *but seems not working* why ? .. what's your desired output ?

Comment: @Taki - the border should not come out of the orange fill, since i use border-box property

Comment: Hang on, I have a solution. I will write an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems in the code: first, as @Daniel pointed out in his answer, the dimensions of the element must be made explicit so as to prevent automatic resizing. Additionally, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168048/using-box-sizing-border-box-with-inline-block-elements), `inline-block` elements conflict with `border-box` sizing, but there are several workarounds.

For one, the CSS attribute `overflow: hidden` can also be added to the element in question. Alternatively, it is possible to use `vertical-align: top` to ensure all elements have the same baseline. A functional example can be seen below, with a larger border for emphasis:

```css
a{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  border:10px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:1rem;
}

a.active{
  border:0;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="active" href="#">EN</a><a href="#">FR</a>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `inline-block' conflicts with the border-box value?

Comment: @Daniel I can't seem to find why, but I am finding more examples of it. For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313792/why-doesnt-border-box-work-on-inline-block-element has the same problem.

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627365/border-box-not-working-on-inline-block-elements can help explain this phenomenon.

Comment: If it is a problem with baseline alignment then setting a `vertical-align: top;` is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the value of the dimension that you want the browser to use the `border-box` calculation for.

As per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#box-sizing) in reference to the `border-box` value:

> The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border
>   and padding widths of the respective sides from the **specified**
>   . As the content width and height cannot be
>   negative, this computation is floored at zero.

So set the width and/or height property for your `a` elements and then the padding/border will be subtracted from this.

`box-sizing: border-box;` values for elements without specified width or height dimensions are ignored.

Comment: See @StardustGogeta answer where an `overflow` property value is used as a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:1rem;
}

a.active{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="active" href="#">EN</a><a href="#">FR</a>
```

I've run into the same issue and think I've found much simpler solution. Instead of removing the border completely just change its color for transparent. That way it is still there even though it's not visible. Thanks to that text inside anchor tag won't jump here and forth.

Comment: when this question was posted I hadn't had anything to do with CSS nor would I thought that in 4 years time I will have any idea as that works. Nevertheless, this may still help someone.